# Circular shift of vector (equivalent to numpy.roll)

Tags: python, r, numpy

I have a vector:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

And I'd like to do something like:

```
b <- roll(a, 2) # 4,5,1,2,3
```

Is there a function like that in R?  I've been googling around, but "R Roll" mostly gives me pages about Spanish pronunciation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about using `head` and `tail`...

```
roll <- function( x , n ){
  if( n == 0 )
    return( x )
  c( tail(x,n) , head(x,-n) )
}

roll(1:5,2)
#[1] 4 5 1 2 3

#  For the situation where you supply 0 [ this would be kinda silly! :) ]
roll(1:5,0)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

One cool thing about using `head` and `tail`... you get a reverse roll with negative `n`, e.g.

```
roll(1:5,-2)
[1] 3 4 5 1 2
```

Answer (score 25):

Here's an alternative which has the advantage of working even when `x` is "rolled" by more than one full cycle (i.e. when `abs(n) > length(x)`):

```
roll <- function(x, n) {
    x[(seq_along(x) - (n+1)) %% length(x) + 1]
}

roll(1:5, 2)
# [1] 4 5 1 2 3
roll(1:5, 0)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
roll(1:5, 11)
# [1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

FWIW (and not that it's worth *much*) it also works on `data.frame`s:

```
head(mtcars, 1)
#           mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
head(roll(mtcars, 2), 1)
#           gear carb mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am
# Mazda RX4    4    4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1
```

Comment: Is there a good mathematical proof that this works? I've proved enough to convince myself, but I've got nothing ironclad.

Answer (score 5):

The package `binhf` has the function `shift`:

```
library(binhf)

shift(1:5, places = 2)
#[1] 4 5 1 2 3
```

*places* can be positive or negative

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `permute` package:

```
require(permute)

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

shuffleSeries(a, start = 2)
```

output:

```
[1] 3 4 5 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

`rearrr` also contains `roll_elements_vec()` for vectors and `roll_elements()` for one or more columns in a data frame.

`roll_elements()` can handle grouped data frames and can find the `n` setting based on the group members with a given function (e.g. `rearrr::median_index()` or `rearrr::quantile_index()`).

Roll a vector -2 positions left (i.e. 2 positions right):

```r
library(rearrr)
library(dplyr)

# Roll vector
roll_elements_vec(1:10, n = -2)

> 9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Roll a column in a data frame -2 positions up:

```r
# Set seed
set.seed(1)

# Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(
    "x" = 1:10,
    "y" = runif(10) * 10,
    "g" = rep(1:2, each = 5)
)

# Roll `x` column
roll_elements(df, cols = "x", n = -2)

> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        y     g     x .n       
>    <dbl> <int> <int> <list>   
>  1 2.66      1     9 <dbl [1]>
>  2 3.72      1    10 <dbl [1]>
>  3 5.73      1     1 <dbl [1]>
>  4 9.08      1     2 <dbl [1]>
>  5 2.02      1     3 <dbl [1]>
>  6 8.98      2     4 <dbl [1]>
>  7 9.45      2     5 <dbl [1]>
>  8 6.61      2     6 <dbl [1]>
>  9 6.29      2     7 <dbl [1]>
> 10 0.618     2     8 <dbl [1]>
```

The `.n` column contains the `n` setting applied. This is mostly useful when finding `n` with a function.

Roll the `x` column within each group in `g`:

```r
# Group by `g` and roll `x` within both groups 
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(g) %>% 
  roll_elements(cols = "x", n = -2)

> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        y     g     x .n       
>    <dbl> <int> <int> <list>   
>  1 2.66      1     4 <dbl [1]>
>  2 3.72      1     5 <dbl [1]>
>  3 5.73      1     1 <dbl [1]>
>  4 9.08      1     2 <dbl [1]>
>  5 2.02      1     3 <dbl [1]>
>  6 8.98      2     9 <dbl [1]>
>  7 9.45      2    10 <dbl [1]>
>  8 6.61      2     6 <dbl [1]>
>  9 6.29      2     7 <dbl [1]>
> 10 0.618     2     8 <dbl [1]>
```

If we don't specify one or more columns, the entire data frame is rolled. As mentioned we can find `n` with a function, so here we will roll by the median index (index is 1:10, so median = 5.5 and rounded to 6 positions up).

```r
# Roll entire data frame 
# Find `n` with the `median_index()` function
roll_elements(df, n_fn = median_index)

> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        x     y     g .n       
>    <int> <dbl> <int> <list>   
>  1     7 9.45      2 <dbl [1]>
>  2     8 6.61      2 <dbl [1]>
>  3     9 6.29      2 <dbl [1]>
>  4    10 0.618     2 <dbl [1]>
>  5     1 2.66      1 <dbl [1]>
>  6     2 3.72      1 <dbl [1]>
>  7     3 5.73      1 <dbl [1]>
>  8     4 9.08      1 <dbl [1]>
>  9     5 2.02      1 <dbl [1]>
> 10     6 8.98      2 <dbl [1]>
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `rearrr`. It also contains a `roll_values()` function for rolling the value of elements instead of their positions.

Answer (score 1):

The `numpy roll` method supports both directions, forward and backward, and it accepts shift parameters greater than the length of the vector. For example:

**Python**

```
import numpy
x=numpy.arange(1,6)
numpy.roll(x,-11)
```

And we get:

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
```

Or

```
x=numpy.arange(1,6)
numpy.roll(x,12)
```

And we get:

```
array([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

We can build an R function that takes into consideration the case where the shift parameter is greater than the length of the vector. For example:

**R**

```
custom_roll <- function( x , n ){
  if( n == 0 | n%%length(x)==0) {
    return(x)
    }
  
  else if (abs(n)>length(x)) {
  new_n<- (abs(n)%%length(x))*sign(n)
  return(c( tail(x,new_n) , head(x,-new_n) ))
  }
  else {
  return(c( tail(x,n) , head(x,-n) ))
  }
}
```

Let's see what we get but taking into consideration again the vector (1,2,3,4,5).

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
custom_roll(x,-11)
```

And we get:

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 1
```

Or

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
custom_roll(x,12)
```

And we get:

```
[1] 4 5 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

From `data.table` version >=1.14.9 (in development; see [NEWS item #27](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1149--in-development)), `shift` supports `type = "cyclic"` "where pushed out values are re-introduced at the front/back".

```
# latest development version that has passed all tests:
# data.table::update_dev_pkg()

library(data.table)
shift(1:5, n = 2, type = "cyclic")
# [1] 4 5 1 2 3
```

`shift` accepts multiple offset values in `n`.

```
shift(1:5, n = -1:1, type = "cyclic")  
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

---

The benchmark in [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1149--in-development) suggests that it is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line solution using indexes and modular arithmetic

```
roll<-function(v,n)
{
  v[(0:(length(v)-1) + n) %% length(v) + 1]
}
```