# Shift all elements of a matrix down one index in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to shift all the elements of a certain matrix by 1 using R. I have a rather large 10x10 matrix that I need to do this for several times. I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient way. For example, I have:

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]  
[1,]    1        4        7
[2,]    2        5        8
[3,]    3        6        9
```

And the goal is for the matrix to look like:

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]  
[1,]    9        3        6
[2,]    1        4        7
[3,]    2        5        8
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your work. How far have you come without help? what have you tried already? how is it failing for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Equivalent to numpy.roll() in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791212/equivalent-to-numpy-roll-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
matrix(c(mat[length(mat)], mat[-length(mat)]),
       nrow = dim(mat)[1])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    9    3    6
#[2,]    1    4    7
#[3,]    2    5    8
```

`c(mat[length(mat)], mat[-length(mat)])` will take the last element from `mat` and puts it at the first position.

We could also do

```
mat[] <- c(mat[length(mat)], mat[-length(mat)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the **shift** function of the **binhf** package gives a simple to understand statement that can allow for arbitrary shifts sizes in either direction:

```
library(binhf)
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)

matrix(shift(mat,places=1),nrow=dim(mat)[1])

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    9    3    6
#[2,]    1    4    7
#[3,]    2    5    8
```

or simply:

```
matrix(shift(mat,1),nrow=dim(mat)[1])
```