# How to roll the order of a fixed length vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this vector:

```
1:12
```

and I want to roll the order of the values in this way:

```
#Iter 1
1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

#Iter 2
12 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

#Iter 3
11 12 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#Iter 3
10 11 12 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

#Iter 4
...

#Iter 12
1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

I try `dplyr:lead`, `seq(to = 1, by = -1, length.out = 12)` and a loop, but I don't know how to do backwards (reverse) slicing in R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular shift of vector (equivalent to numpy.roll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791212/circular-shift-of-vector-equivalent-to-numpy-roll).  You can do `lapply(seq_along(x), function(n) c(tail(x, n), head(x, -n)))`.

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
vec <- 1:12
#List
List <- list()
List[[1]] <- vec
#Loop
for(i in 2:length(vec))
{
  List[[i]] <- vec[c((length(vec)-2)+2,1:length(vec)-1)]
  vec <- List[[i]]
}

[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[2]]
 [1] 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

[[3]]
 [1] 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[4]]
 [1] 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

[[5]]
 [1]  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8

[[6]]
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

[[7]]
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6

[[8]]
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5

[[9]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4

[[10]]
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3

[[11]]
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2

[[12]]
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1
```