# How to generate random two concentric spheres synthetic data?

Tags: matlab, random, plot, synthetic

How to generate random two concentric spheres synthetic data with `radius1=40` and `radius2 =100` in MATLAB and save that data in format `*.mat` with one variable.`(1000*3 double)`? Also, how to plot this data in 3D with 2 colors: red and blue?

**My Code:**

```
rng(0,'twister');
rvals = 2*rand(1000,1)-1;
elevation = asin(rvals);

azimuth = 2*pi*rand(1000,1);

radii = 3*(rand(1000,1).^(1/3));

[x,y,z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,radii);
data=[x,y,z];
figure
plot3(x,y,z,'.');
axis equal
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. Are the points distributed uniformly? Do you mean on the surfaces of each of the two spheres or in the space between exterior of the smaller sphere and the interior of the larger one?

Comment: uniformly distributed in 2 class.N=1000, class1 =N/2 , class 2=N/2, i want generate data set .i have not code

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Edit your original question to improve it.

Comment: ok .It is very important for me
Link is similar to existing photo.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033614/how-to-draw-a-crystal-ball-with-two-color-particles-inside) some answers might give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fixed radius then assign them a **constant value** (instead of a random value) and keep the random numbers for the orientation angles (`azimuth/elevation` or `theta/phi` depending on notation).

This code:

```
rng(0,'twister');
nptSet = 500 ; r1 = 40 ; r2 = 100 ;                 %// your constraints

%// first data set (r1=40)
r1    = zeros(nptSet,1)+r1  ;           %// assign radius (fixed)
azi1  = rand( size(r1) ) * 2*pi ;       %// random azimuth   [  0     2pi]
elev1 = (rand(size(r1)) .* pi)-pi/2 ;   %// random elevation [-pi/2  pi/2]

%// second data set (r2=100)
r2    = zeros(nptSet,1)+r2  ;           %// assign radius (fixed)
azi2  = rand( size(r2) ) * 2*pi ;       %// random azimuth   [  0     2pi]
elev2 = (rand(size(r2)) .* pi)-pi/2 ;   %// random elevation [-pi/2  pi/2]

%// convert to cartesian
[x1,y1,z1] = sph2cart(azi1,elev1,r1);
[x2,y2,z2] = sph2cart(azi2,elev2,r2);

%// display and refine
figure ; hold on
plot3(x1,y1,z1,'or','MarkerSize',2);
plot3(x2,y2,z2,'+b');
xlabel('x') ; ylabel('y') ; zlabel('z')
axis equal ; grid off ; view(50,30)
```

Will get you that figure:
[image: spheredots]

Comment: this is just WRONG. While azimuth is uniform in [0...2 pi], elevation is NOT uniform. You cannot sample angle uniformly and expect points in space to be uniformly distributed. The uniformly distributed thing is cosine of elevation. And elevation itself is typically in [0...pi] range

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, it was a mistake in the comment only, the elevation wasn't in the [-pi pi] range but in the `[-pi/2 pi/2]` range. So a total span of `pi` indeed. I guess that's how Matlab expects it as input for `sph2cart` because if I distribute the elevation on `[0 pi]` I only get the top half dome.

Comment: ok, I see now, yes, total range is \pi, if Matlab prefers it to be from -pi/2 to pi/2 so be it. My real problem with your answer is that it is not uniform in space with elevation sampled as you wrote. Why? Because of a Jacobian. Uniform in space means `density * dx * dy * dx`, so each volume of `dx * dy *dz` has same number of points. If we go to spherical coordinates, we'll get a Jacobian, thus equal to `density * r^2 dr * sin(e) de * da` where `e` is elevation and `a` is azimuth. It is uniform in azimuth `a`, so one can sample it in [0...2\pi] range. It is NOT uniform in `e` due to sin

Comment: here is useful link to unit sphere sampling with wrong sampling being uniform in angles http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 1):

Easy, sample in spherical coordinates

```
phi = 2 * Pi * U(0,1)
cos(theta) = 2 * U(0,1) - 1
r          = r_min * U(0,1)^(1/3) (r_max - r_min)

sin(theta) = sqrt(1-cos^2(theta))
x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi)
y = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
z = r * cos(theta)
```

Comment: i want r1=40 and r2=100