# Disribute particles uniformly inside a sphere with huge radius (10^9) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I would like some help with the following:

```
   L2=10^9;
   nP=10^6;

   x(:,1)=L2.*rand(nP,1);
   y(:,1)=L2.*rand(nP,1);   % Select  initial partice position randomly (only positive values) NS
   z(:,1)= L2.*rand(nP,1);


   for ip=1:nP
      r1(ip,1)= sqrt(x(ip,1)^2 + y(ip,1)^2 + z(ip,1)^2);   % distance from (0,0,0) for each iteration

      while r1(ip,1)>=L2

         x(ip,1)=L2.*rand(1,1);
         y(ip,1)=L2.*rand(1,1);     % Select  initial partice position randomly (only positive values) NS
         z(ip,1)=L2.*rand(1,1);
         r1(ip,1)= sqrt(x(ip,1)^2 + y(ip,1)^2 + z(ip,1)^2);
      end
   end
```

The problems I face are:

1) Since the radius L2 is very big, when I multiply with L2 with rand I get values very close to the boundaries of the box (10^8 for example) and I want the particles uniformly distributed all around the sphere.

2) Also after I run the while command the resulting distributions are no more uniform.

Comment: Why do you say the points are close to the boundaries? And why do you say they are not randomly distributed? Your code looks correct to me. I think you didn’t evaluate the result correctly (except for what I assume are typos, as there are some syntax errors).

Comment: Note that `10^9` is better written as `1e9`.

Comment: I corrected the two syntax errors in your code, please make sure it matches the code you were running.

Comment: If you have a sphere, then you might want to generate your random points using spherical coordinates.  Given the shape of a sphere, there is a lot more volume near the outer boundary than near the centre.  Some bias towards the boundary is to be expected.

Comment: This question was asking about points distributed on the sphere _surface_ but you may find some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158433/how-to-generate-random-two-concentric-spheres-synthetic-data/30174449#30174449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually this can be accomplished in three stages:

1. Generate points on the surface of a unit sphere;
2. Scale each point to fill the interior of the sphere uniformly; and
3. Rescale them to the desired radius.

In practice the steps can be combined.

Note that I'm not a Matlab user, nor do I have a copy of it, so please treat what follows as pseudocode.

The simplest and most general way to generate points randomly distributed on the surface of a *k*-dimensional sphere, while avoiding the acceptance/rejection approach, is to generate *k* independent standard normals and normalize each resulting point by its distance from the origin.  For three dimensions:

```
x = randn
y = randn
z = randn
scale_factor = 1 / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
x = x * scale_factor
y = y * scale_factor
z = z * scale_factor
```

To scale the points to the interior of the sphere, you want to apply a scale factor between 0 and 1.  However, if you scale the factor uniformly the result will not be three dimensionally uniform. Note that a sphere with radius 1/2 has only 1/8 the volume of a unit sphere, so we need to adjust the scale factor accordingly to make the expected number of points proportional to the volume.  The correct scale factor for a *k*-dimensional sphere is to take the *k*-th root of a uniform(0,1) random number (see [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) for a 2-d illustration of this principle), so in your case you want to adjust the scale factor using a cube root.  Change the `scale_factor` above to:

```
scale_factor = (rand^(1/3)) / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```

Finally, to rescale to your actual desired radius of `L2`, what you actually want is:

```
scale_factor = L2 * (rand^(1/3)) / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```