# Plot points on a sphere in R

Tags: r, visualization

Could you help me to make a plot similar to this in R?

[image]

I would like to have it interactive such that I could rotate the sphere. I guess I should use `rgl`. I found an example similar to what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033614/how-to-draw-a-crystal-ball-with-two-color-particles-inside/29873862), however I couldn't find a way to draw a grid instead of a filled sphere.

**UPD:** A reproducible dataset that could help answering the question (I took it from [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Visualizing-Points-on-a-Sphere-td3324420.html)):

```
u <- runif(1000,0,1) 
v <- runif(1000,0,1) 
theta <- 2 * pi * u 
phi   <- acos(2 * v - 1) 
x <- sin(theta) * cos(phi) 
y <- sin(theta) * sin(phi) 
z <- cos(theta) 
library("lattice") 
cloud(z ~ x + y)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start with

```
library("rgl")
spheres3d(0,0,0,lit=FALSE,color="white")
spheres3d(0,0,0,radius=1.01,lit=FALSE,color="black",front="lines")
```

to create a "wireframe" sphere (I'm cheating a little bit here by drawing two spheres, one a little bit larger than the other ... there may be a better way to do this, but I couldn't easily/quickly figure it out).

from the [Wolfram web page on sphere point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) (the source of your picture) we get

> Similarly, we can pick u=cos(phi) to be uniformly distributed (so we have du=sin phi dphi) and obtain the points `x = sqrt(1-u^2)*cos(theta)`; `y = sqrt(1-u^2)*sin(theta)`; `z=u` with theta in [0,2pi) and u in [-1,1], which are also uniformly distributed over S^2.

So:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 50
theta <- runif(n,0,2*pi)
u <- runif(n,-1,1)
x <- sqrt(1-u^2)*cos(theta)
y <- sqrt(1-u^2)*sin(theta)
z <- u
spheres3d(x,y,z,col="red",radius=0.02)
```

The spheres take a little more effort to render but are prettier than the results of `points3d()` (flat squares) ...

[image]

Comment: A note for Mavericks+ Mac users. If you compile from the source of the current version: rgl_0.95.1435, you may get better results than with the binary version on CRAN.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid showing the back points on the sphere? To make it not transparent?

Answer (score 3):

Wandering in late,  I might suggest looking at the packages `sphereplot` and, if you're feeling really brave,  `gensphere` for highly configurable general placement of points in 3-space.

`sphereplot` includes simple functions such as (quoting from the man pages)

> pointsphere *Random sphere pointing*
>    **Description**   Randomly generates data
>   points within a sphere that are uniformly distributed.
>   **Usage**
>   pointsphere(N = 100, longlim = c(0, 360), latlim = c(-90, 90), rlim =
>   c(0, 1))
>   **Arguments** 
>   N Number of random points.
>   longlim Limits of longitude in degrees.
>   latlim Limits of latitude in degrees.
>   rlim  Limits of radius.